# SQL Group By on calculated column - invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

as I am exporting data from DB to a client, I'm facing a SQL issue

My working request is :

```sql
select 
    datmvt as DATE_MVT,
    (select TRUNC(datmvt,-4) from dual ) as exercice,
    codpro as CODPRO,
    SUM(qtemvt)-SUM(C01) as QT
from myTable
where codpro = 'XXX'
and datmvt BETWEEN YYYYMMDD and YYYYMMDD
GROUP BY datmvt, codpro
HAVING abs(SUM(qtemvt)-SUM(C01)) > 0
```

Giving me this result :

```
DATMVT    exercice   codpro        QT
20190119  20190000  0828765332927  1
20190126  20190000  0828765332927  -1
20180117  20180000  0828765332927  -1
20180118  20180000  0828765332927  -1
20190122  20190000  0828765332927  1
```

Before you ask, yes, dates are stored as Integer values with YYYYMMDD format.
My request is working but I would like to have somehting like :

```
exercice  codpro         QT
20190000  0828765332927  -1
20180000  0828765332927  -2
```

So ofc I'm trying to order by `exercice` but Oracle respond me with : `00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"`

Here my non-working--but-needed request :

```sql
select 
    (select TRUNC(datmvt,-4) from dual ) as exercice,
    codpro as CODPRO,
    SUM(qtemvt)-SUM(C01) as QT
from myTable
where codpro = 'XXX'
and datmvt BETWEEN YYYYMMDD and YYYYMMDD
GROUP BY exercice, codpro
HAVING abs(SUM(qtemvt)-SUM(C01)) > 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only refer to columns existing in the dataset in your `GROUP BY`, so you'll need to repeat that calculation there as well, something like:

```
select 
    TRUNC(datmvt,-4) as exercice,
    codpro as CODPRO,
    SUM(qtemvt)-SUM(C01) as QT
from myTable
where codpro = 'XXX'
and datmvt BETWEEN YYYYMMDD and YYYYMMDD
GROUP BY TRUNC(datmvt,-4), codpro
HAVING abs(SUM(qtemvt)-SUM(C01)) > 0
```

[Working example on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=27e3e6c7c215cc31f1a3cbd9f7728c45)

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong or something you've not mentioned, [because it works just fine](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=27e3e6c7c215cc31f1a3cbd9f7728c45).

Comment: Well I propably missed somehting when trying. It's indeed working.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why did you use subquery `(select TRUNC(datmvt,-4) from dual)` for dates, when you can do it without it. You can do select from select, but this syntax is simpler and should do the job:

```
select trunc(datmvt,-4) exercice, codpro, sum(qtemvt)-sum(c01) qt
  from mytable
  where codpro = '0828765332927' and datmvt between 20150101 and 20191231
  group by trunc(datmvt, -4), codpro
  having sum(qtemvt) - sum(c01) <> 0
```

**<sup>[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ab81bf430314cc2b527a3a9a3f2e3afa)</sup>**